# awesome wm font issue

Tags: awesome

I have an [awesome-copycats](https://github.com/lcpz/awesome-copycats/) conf and since last Arch Linux update I have no more font on the topbar widget. Every single character is a square.

That is affecting taglist, clock and so on.

Basically what is defined by:

```
theme.font                                      = "xos4 Terminus 9"
```

from [`theme.lua`](https://github.com/lcpz/awesome-copycats/blob/master/themes/powerarrow-dark/theme.lua#L20)

I checked if that `xos4 Terminus` is still here, and that seems to be the case.

```bsh
fc-list | grep Terminus 
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x12b.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x22b.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x32b.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x18b.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x20b.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x28b.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x16b.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x14n.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x14b.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x24n.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x24b.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x16n.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x18n.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x20n.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x28n.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x12n.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x22n.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/misc/ter-x32n.pcf.gz: xos4 Terminus:style=Regular
```

I also tried to change it by another font. But that does not make the trick.

Any idea on how I could have it work?

Comment: In my case (Gentoo Linux) Terminus fonts require bitmap fonts enabled. One way to do this is making a link from `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/70-yes-bitmaps.conf` to `/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-yes-bitmaps.conf`. I hope this helps:| There is also an alias for terminus in `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/75-yes-terminus.conf` which may not be necessary.

Comment: I solved font issues with 2 steps. 1st I install `gtk2fontsel` and saw that some fonts where corrupted. Then I could select working one. But I still had some issue with notifications boxes. Not whole text was shown. So I update [`lcpz/lain`](https://github.com/lcpz/lain/) which is strongly linked to `awesome-copycats`.

Comment: @mickro can you tell me how you updated lain? I have the same issue.

Comment: I've `lain` linked to its github repository. So I simply `git pull`. And that fallen in order.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Pango, the library that Awesome WM uses to render fonts, has dropped support for bitmap fonts. I have installed the TTF version of Terminus and specified it in my theme file like so:

```
theme.font = "Terminus (TTF) 12"
```

Depending on your font rendering settings, you may need to adjust how Terminus is rendered in your `.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`, but it looks like at least the Arch Linux package of Terminus TTF comes with necessary config files to disable anti-aliasing.