# Weird fonts in awesome window manager in arch linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xorg, window-manager, awesome

[image]

I installed awesome window manager on arch linux and started it with xinit. All fonts are appearing as weird boxes everywhere including the window manager title bars. Fonts inside programs like xterm are fine. Please see the above image.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you mind editing your post to include the version of ArchLinux you are running?

Comment: I am running arch 245.5-8. Linux kernal ver. 5.7.9

Answer (score 0):

Please try specifying a different font: https://superuser.com/questions/797237/awesomewm-how-to-change-statusbar-font-colors-and-font-itself

This might explain why you're seeing this: [awesome wm font issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534813/awesome-wm-font-issue)